# Best way to replace \x00 in list of strings?

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-2.6

I have a list of values from a parsed PE file that include `\x00` null bytes at the end of each section.  I want to be able to remove the `\x00` bytes from the string without removing all `"x"`s from the file.  I have tried doing `.replace()` and `re.sub()`, but not with much success.

Using Python 2.6.6

Example.

```
import re

List = [['.text\x00\x00\x00'], ['.data\x00\x00\x00'], ['.rsrc\x00\x00\x00']]

count = 0
while count < len(List):
    test = re.sub('\\\\x00', '', str(List[count]))
    print test
    count += 1
```

Output:

```
['.text']
['.data']
['.rsrc']
```

I want to get the following output:

```
.text
.data
.rsrc
```

Any ideas on the best way of going about this?

Comment: Just use `\x00` if you really want to remove the null byte.

Comment: Don't name your variable after a type (List). You're asking for trouble.

Comment: PEP8 aside, you're not going to get into any trouble using `List` which is distinct from `list` (which could cause subtle bugs).

Comment: Maybe the Python interpreter won't hang you, but your co-workers will. It's a slippery slope, and invites for bad variable names.

Comment: If think you meant `str(List[count])` in your code.

Comment: @martineau you're correct.  I quickly typed it in generically from the code and mistyped it.

Comment: The bracket characters are in the output because you're removing the null bytes from the string representation of the *one of the nested lists*: i.e. `"['.text\x00\x00\x00']"`, `"['.data\x00\x00\x00']"`, etc. Change the `re.sub` line to `test = re.sub('\x00', '', List[count][0])` and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> L = [['.text\x00\x00\x00'], ['.data\x00\x00\x00'], ['.rsrc\x00\x00\x00']]
>>> [[x[0]] for x in L]
[['.text\x00\x00\x00'], ['.data\x00\x00\x00'], ['.rsrc\x00\x00\x00']]
>>> [[x[0].replace('\x00', '')] for x in L]
[['.text'], ['.data'], ['.rsrc']]
```

Or to modify the list in place instead of creating a new one:

```
for x in L:
    x[0] = x[0].replace('\x00', '')
```

Comment: Yo dont need to make new lists or make replacements, where you can use iterators. They are free to make. They are literally transformation expression.

Comment: @LukaRahne Are you talking about generator expressions? Anyway this is just a small example, depending on the OP's needs he can do that if he wants

Comment: is there a way to get rid of the brackets in the list to get just the data values?  example.  [['.text'], ['.data]] and I wanted to do a loop through the index say  section in sectionlist then on the next line put section[0], it would give me the value ['text'], but I just want .text.  How can you do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
lst = (i[0].rstrip('\x00') for i in List)
for j in lst: 
   print j,
```

Answer (score 4):

Try a unicode pattern, like this:

```
re.sub(u'\x00', '', s)
```

It should give the following results:

```
l = [['.text\x00\x00\x00'], ['.data\x00\x00\x00'], ['.rsrc\x00\x00\x00']]
for x in l:
    for s in l:
        print re.sub(u'\x00', '', s)
        count += 1

.text
.data
.rsrc
```

Or, using list comprehensions:

```
[[re.sub(u'\x00', '', s) for s in x] for x in l]
```

Actually, should work without the 'u' in front of the string. Just remove the first 3 slashes, and use this as your regex pattern:

```
'\x00'
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're really wanting to do is replace `'\x00'` characters in *strings* in a list.

Towards that goal, people often overlook the fact that in Python 2 the non-Unicode string [`translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) method will also optionally (or only) delete 8-bit characters as illustrated below. (It doesn't accept this argument in Python 3 because strings are Unicode objects by default.)

Your `List` data structure seems a little odd, since it's a list of one-element lists consisting of just single strings. Regardless, in the code below I've renamed it `sections` since Capitalized words should only be used for the names of classes according to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
sections = [['.text\x00\x00\x00'], ['.data\x00\x00\x00'], ['.rsrc\x00\x00\x00']]

for section in sections:
    test = section[0].translate(None, '\x00')
    print test
```

Output:

```
.text
.data
.rsrc
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way to take care of this particular problem is to use the following function:

```
import string

for item  in List:
  filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, str(item))
```

This will get rid of not just \x00 but any other such hex values that are appended to your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

List = [['.text\x00\x00\x00'], ['.data\x00\x00\x00'], ['.rsrc\x00\x00\x00']]    
new_list = [x.replace("\x00", "") for x in chain(*List)]
#['.text', '.data', '.rsrc']
```